# EXC_BAD_ACCESS within controllerDidChangeContent: at line tableView.endUpdates()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This is my all `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`:

```
//MARK: - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(newIndexPath)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    case .Delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(indexPath)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    case .Update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(indexPath)) as? WLCommentTableViewCell {
                updateCell(cell, withIndexPath: indexPath)
            }
        }
    case .Move:
        if let indexPath = indexPath, let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(indexPath)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(newIndexPath)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {

    tableView.endUpdates() //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)
    updateView()

    if shouldScrollTableToBottom {
        scrollTableViewToBottom()
    }
}
```

Sometimes my app crashes at line with `tableView.endUpdates()`. Why?

Comment: Are you sure about the count of your datasource, I mean the number of rows before update and after update, are those same. Please check that, it might help.

Comment: I am pretty sure they are the same:) I pay attention about this

Answer (score 1):

The line

```swift
    tableView.endUpdates() //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)
```

should go inside the NSFetchresultsController delegate method that informs you of all the changes have finished:

> controllerDidChangeContent: Notifies the receiver that the fetched results controller has completed processing of one or more changes due
>   to an add, remove, move, or update.

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
     updateView()

    if shouldScrollTableToBottom {
        scrollTableViewToBottom()
    }
    tableView.endUpdates() // Mark here no more updates to the tableview
}
```

> endUpdates: Concludes a series of method calls that insert, delete, select, or reload rows and sections of the table view.
>   You call this method to bracket a series of method calls that begins with beginUpdates and that consists of operations to insert, delete, select, and reload rows and sections of the table view. When you call endUpdates, UITableView animates the operations simultaneously. Invocations of beginUpdates and endUpdates can be nested. **If you do not make the insertion, deletion, and selection calls inside this block, table attributes such as row count can become invalid**.

Comment: Think of endUpdates as a transition-finishing method: call it when you are set inserting, moving or deleting cells.